# Jet Boat Engine Part Identification

Tags: materials, bearings, machine-elements

[image]

If anyone can provide me information about this part right here, please tell me.

Answer (score 7):

It is a high pressure seal and bearing unit.

The metal assembly to the right with the yellow parts is the drive coupling.

After Sam’s comment and looking at that part again, there are 3 distinct metal parts - the middle one with the holes is aluminium, while the outer two are the outer races of the two bearings.

Two bearings are often used due to either the load, controlling end float or controlling play or vibration in the shaft.

Comment: Indeed, as it placed inside the housing at the end of the main shaft, and having a lubrication boring hole all of those indicate bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Combined thrust bearing and shaft seal / stuffing box. Yes, it's really called that.

The nipple on top is to inject lubricant which has dual function of preventing water ingress to engine compartment.

The thrust unit forward loads cannot be transferred to drive shaft / engine without:

1. damage
2. or serious design compromise

The thrust bearing transfers these loads to the housing which is of course secured to the hull & framing. This also improves thrust vector geometry.

Answer (score -1):

It's a boat jet engine. And as Solar Mike's answer says, it is a bearing and seal. I guess it is a brush less electrical motor.

Here is a link to an eBay ad. [ElectricalJet motor](https://www.ebay.com/i/282171897630?chn=ps&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=282171897630&targetid=541454106452&device=m&adtype=pla&googleloc=9031022&poi=&campaignid=1669934873&adgroupid=65058351339&rlsatarget=pla-541454106452&abcId=1139336&merchantid=113679796&gclid=Cj0KCQjwt_nmBRD0ARIsAJYs6o3EJLz2Ff_hVHIE0sz2awrof8O1eLN__qlMJ4CyMAfESd_X6F5OoUoaAstQEALw_wcB)

Comment: It's tempting to  think that, butI believe this is not correct, if it is, there is a lack of bearing on the shaft which implies a major flaw in design, and where does the other end of elastic coupling go? Meanwhile i found this two links, https://www.mhz-watercraft.com/media/pdf/45/11/f0/Jets.pdf
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e87Oleg5Q4s

Answer (score -2):

my guess is a stater which is a thing that connects to a rotating shaft and creates electricity by rotating a magnetic field from a magnet against coils. and the other  prop is a impeller which pulls water towards it instead of pushing water out the back of it.

Comment: What makes you think it's electrical? There's an alignment coupling on the right end that would be where it is attached to the drive motor.